# How do i print ETA in tensorflow as I do in Keras with verbose

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, epoch

I need to have the the estimated time it will take to train my model in Tensorflow with each epoch . In keras when i predict the classes with verbose , I get something like this :

```
Epoch 1/70 17800/34960 [==============>...............] - ETA: 22s - 
loss: 7.3802 - acc: 0.0631
34960/34960 [==============================] - 44s 1ms/step - loss: 7.1693 - 
acc: 0.0641 
Epoch 2/70 34960/34960 [==============================] - 42s 
1ms/step - loss: 6.7803 - acc: 0.0646
Epoch 3/70 34960/34960 
[==============================] - 43s 1ms/step - loss: 6.6338 - acc: 0.0678 
Epoch 4/70 5200/34960 [===>..........................] - ETA: 36s - loss: 
6.3998 - acc: 0.0737
34960/34960 [==============================] - 43s 1ms/step - loss: 6.4653 - 
acc: 0.0753 
Epoch 5/70 34960/34960 [==============================] - 43s
```

How can I get same type of info in Tensorflow only . When i print (tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO), it gives 'None'

Comment: How did you build your model? Is it an estimator? Or a custom tensorflow model with a training loop that you wrote yourself?

Comment: I'm working on leaked GAN's . So there is pre training the discriminator , pre training generator, then adversial training for Generator and finally adversial training for Discriminator . It has training loops within it .

Comment: Have a look at the tqdm python library. It's a non-tensorflow solution, but it's something that can get you close to the keras progress bar https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm